# Soft Start for AC incandescent lamp

Tags: soft-starter

i want to make a soft starter for incandescent lamp.

i have seen some [magical dimmer](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?country=nl&lang=en&id=366308) or [Russian soft start device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejP7r9x8weI&t=164s) which are not available near me.

i found some [diagram](https://www.diagram.com.ua/list/sprav/sprav238.shtml) of the Russian soft start device but could not find the required КР1182ПМ1 chip.

[this circuit did not work](https://cxem.net/house/1-375.php) first but someone commented [this in that site](https://cxem.net/ckfinder/userfiles/comments/36424_111.jpg) and it worked somehow. problem is one resistor gets bloody hot and lamp does not get full brightness. probably gets only 80% bright.

i made some diy vactrol with LED and LDR and soft start the LED with ATtiny85 microcontroller. then used that LDR pins as a variable resistor of a simple triac based ac fan regulator. used the regulator in series with the lamp. and it worked well. only problem is i have to power up the microcontroller separately. i wanted something very small and to put in series with the lamp.

now recently i tried [this version II](http://danyk.cz/plynule_en.html) and it is working. lamp gets about 95% bright i guess. main dropping resistor gets hot. i will try higher wattage resistor. otherwise its working. only problem is it not to use in series with the lamp.

if you have some useful information please let me know.

thank you

Comment: The right NTC thermistor will do it. They used to sell NTC thermistor discs with a rubber border to keep it in your bulb socket.

Comment: I own Lutron Diva dimmer. It has a soft start.

Comment: Make yourself a Rusky friend that will send you those pieces. Looking the datasheet it is really russian style. - dirty simple, just enough to works. U2008B has more features, but yes I never liked the idea of that big hot resistor.

Comment: thank you for your answers. i really like Russian technology about electronics. but i most of the time i can not source required parts for a project.